# QT dynamically generate label, LineEdit, Button

Tags: c++, qt

I want to do serial communication in the QT inside, according to the number of serial ports to dynamically generate label, LineEdit, Button, and these three buttons can pull down the scroll bar when the size of the interface, how to do well, I write this below is dead of.
[image]

The effect of encapsulation into a method

[image]

[image]

[image]

The interface was washed last

Comment: Don't post screenshots of your code... Just post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void BaseUi::BaseScrollArea()
{
    QScrollArea *pArea = new QScrollArea();
    QWidget *pWidget = new QWidget();
    pWidget->setStyleSheet("QWidget" "{background:white;}");
    m_vbox_layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    m_vbox_layout->addSpacerItem(new QSpacerItem(100, 30, 
    QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding));
    pWidget->setLayout(m_vbox_layout);
    pArea->setWidget(pWidget);
    pArea->setWidgetResizable(true);
    m_main_layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    m_main_layout->addWidget(pArea);
}

void BaseUi::addAutoRecordUi(QString lab_neme, QString ledit_name)
{
     QWidget *page = new QWidget;
     QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout(page);

     QLabel *label = new QLabel;
     label->setText(lab_neme);
     label->setFont(font());

    QLineEdit *ledit = new QLineEdit;
    ledit->setText(ledit_name);
    ledit->setFont(font());

    layout->addWidget(label, 0, 1);
    layout->addWidget(ledit, 0, 2);

    page->setLayout(layout);

    m_vbox_layout->insertWidget(m_vbox_layout->count()-1, page);

}

 void BaseUi::addMulRecordUi(QString lab_neme, QString ledit_name, QString 
      but_name)
 {
    QWidget *page = new QWidget;
    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout(page);

    QLabel *label = new QLabel;
    label->setText(lab_neme);
    label->setFont(font());

   QLineEdit *ledit = new QLineEdit;
   ledit->setText(ledit_name);
   ledit->setFont(font());

   QPushButton *but = new QPushButton(but_name);
   but->setFont(font());

   layout->addWidget(label, 0, 1);
   layout->addWidget(ledit, 0, 2);
   layout->addWidget(but, 0, 3);

   page->setLayout(layout);

   m_vbox_layout->insertWidget(m_vbox_layout->count()-1, page);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Define QGridLayout insude QScrollArea. And add your new widgets into
   that layout in code. QGridLayout::addWidget
2. Define table where you will show several widgets in table cells. That real complicated way.